# When opening "/tmp/foo.html", don't prompt for Document Title

Tags: hooks, html

If I do "ctrl-x ctrl-f /tmp/foo.html" (where /tmp/foo.html doesn't exist), emacs prompts me for "Document Title:"

How do I turn off this behavior (which I'm guessing is an html-mode hook of some sort).

Apologies if this question is too simple for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grep` does not find a match for `Document Title` in the Lisp source code delivered with GNU Emacs (including `autoinsert.el`).  This behavior is perhaps provided by a 3rd-party library (or that prompt could be dynamically generated, or it could be in the C source code).

Do you see the same thing if you start Emacs using `emacs -Q` (i.e., with no init file)? If not, recursively bisect your init file to find the culprit code. You can use command `comment-region` to comment or (with `C-u`) uncomment a region of text in your init file. Comment out 1/2, then 3/4,, 7/8,... until you find the cause.

Comment: Thanks! "emacs -Q" worked, so I will bisect code as suggested. I'm guessing it's one of the "html-helper" commands, but not sure which one

Answer (score 0):

You may have `auto-insert-mode` enabled. Try `M-x auto-insert-mode` to toggle this minor mode.

When enabled, Emacs will insert a template based on the mode of the new file and prompt you to fill in fields of that template.

This may be enabled by default. You can disable it permanently in your Emacs init file, or just use `M-x customize-option auto-insert-mode` and disable it there.

Comment: Thanks! I customized the "auto-insert" (there was no "auto-insert-mode") variable to "do nothing", did "Save", and even re-did "customize-option" to confirm it was off, but the bad behavior continues.